# How to override Auth::attempt($array) in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Currently `Auth::attempt($array)` will return Boolean, Is there any way to override the default laravel functionality.

That it should return some value instead of Boolean.

Comment: It's possible but registering your own authentication guard and setting it as the default in your config, but it's too much effort for such a simple change. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Is there any documentation for registering our own authentication guard.

Comment: Of course: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: In boot() is it possible to extend 2 controllers Those will be like this `Test_A Controller implements UserProvider`, `Test_BController implements GuardContract`. Can I extend those 2 to Auth facade.

Comment: The `Auth` facade is essentially the `Guard`. The `UserProvider` is used by the guard to get users and verify their credentials. You add guards using `Auth::extend` and you add providers using `Auth::provider`. However the idea of having controllers implement this feels very wrong.